# Prevent Liquibase migrating public schema in Postgres and only migrate configured schemas

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, liquibase

I'm using `org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4` with an instance of the official Postgres Docker image running via `docker-compose`.

The database has the `public` schema by default, and I manually create schemas; `001` and `002` each for a separate tenant.

The problem is that on application start-up, Liquibase executes the changelogs against `public`.

How I can get Liquibase to only execute the changelogs against the 2 configured schemas? i.e `001` and `002`

My Liquibase configuration to run migration changelogs on application start-up:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class})
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LiquibaseConfiguration.class);

  private final Environment env;

  public LiquibaseConfiguration(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
      DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("config/liquibase/changelog/changelog-root.xml");
    return liquibase;
  }

  @Bean
  @DependsOn("liquibase") // ensure execution after SpringLiquibase Bean
  public MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibaseMt(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

    MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibase = new MultiTenantSpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("config/liquibase/changelog/changelog-root.xml");
    liquibase.setSchemas(Arrays.asList("001", "002"));
    return liquibase;
  }
}
```

And a default `DataSource`:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("postgres");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is the fact that `SpringLiquibase` will by default auto run the changelog on the configured datasource, and for Postgres if no schema is specified the SQL scripts will be executed on the `public` aka default schema. So you have two choices to do to stop liquibase from auto-executing against the default schema.

1. Just disable the autorun on `SpringLiquibase`. There is a specific configuration property which can be used to disable/enable the autorun functionality. The property name is `shouldRun`. So just set the value to false and the changelog will not be executed against the default schema.

   ```
   @Bean
   public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
   DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
     SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
     liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
     liquibase.setChangeLog("config/liquibase/changelog/changelog-root.xml");
     // here we tell the system not to run by default
     liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
     return liquibase;
   }
   ```
2. You can totally disable default functionality for spring liquibase by excluding the `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration` and just creating the `MultiTenantSpringLiquibase` bean and delete the `SpringLiquibase` bean creation.

To disable spring liquibase auto-configuration exclude the `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration`

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Delete the creation of `SpringLiquibase` bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class})
public class LiquibaseConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibaseMt(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

    MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibase = new MultiTenantSpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("config/liquibase/changelog/changelog-root.xml");
    liquibase.setSchemas(Arrays.asList("001", "002"));
    return liquibase;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing almost  same issue, but I don't have configuration class I'm using application.yml 
and while deploying to test environment the liquibase takes "PUBLIC" as default database and i see in logs something about H2 database too which i don't understand why it's using it in test environment ! 
in the end I want the same as demanded in this topic just with using application.yml and not a configuration class ! is that possible ?